# textfielddidbegin editing not updating label

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel, func

My swift code below goal is when the user enters something into textfield tt it reflects it in currentPageLabel. The func that I thought would do this is having no effect. Nothing I enter into the textfield displays on the label. All of my code does not use a storyboard.

```
var currentPageLabel = UILabel()
var tt = UITextfield()

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    currentPageLabel.text = tt.text
}
```

Comment: You can add a target to your tt field for editingChanged inside viewDidLoad method and provide a selector to update your label

Comment: If you would like that method textFieldDidBeginEditing  to be called you would need to make your UIViewController conform to UITextFieldDelegate and set your view controller as your text field delegate inside viewDidLoad method. Note that it will be called before the user has a chance to type anything on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let text = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    currentPageLabel.text = text
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addTarget` feature in this case! Just add target to your `textField` in `viewDidload` method, and add selector method marked with `@objc textFieldDidChange`. Inside `textFieldDidChange` function set text to your label!

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)


@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    currentPageLabel.text = textField.text
}
```